# Scala iterate through list except last element

Tags: scala, for-loop

Using a for loop, how can I iterate through a list, with the ability to not iterate over the very last element in the list.

In my case, I would like to not iterate over the first element, and need to iterate through backwards, here is what I have:

```
        for( thing <- things.reverse) {
          //do some computation iterating over every element; 
          //break out of loop when first element is reached
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can drop the first item before you reverse it:

```
for(thing <- things.drop(1).reverse) {
}
```

For lists, `drop(1)` is the same as `tail` if the list is non-empty:

```
for(thing <- things.tail.reverse) {
}
```

or you could do the reverse first and use `dropRight`:

```
for(thing <- things.reverse.dropRight(1)) {
}
```

You can also use `init` if the list is non-empty:

```
for(thing <- things.reverse.init) {
}
```

Comment: You can use `init` and `tail` instead of `dropRight` and `drop`

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - Thanks, I've updated the answer. They require the list be non-empty though so they aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Since it's pretty much a throw-away value, I'd recommend (as for other things like it), throwing a `.view` (better in theory, in practice doesn't always work very well) or a `.iterator` (awkward interface, but pretty well supported) to avoid actually constructing the reversed/dropped value.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Régis, `for(thing <- things.tail.reverse) {}`